# How to authenticate SockJS CONNECT with JWT in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-websocket, sockjs

I am trying to connect to a topic with SockJS, but the response I get is 401 Unauthorized. The project contains Spring security with JWT Authentication. Searching through internet I found that I should authenticate the user in a interceptor. The problem is that my interceptor is not reached.

Everything works fine in a POC (proof of concept) application without Spring security.

I hope I described the problem properly, thanks in advance.

The interceptor that authenticates the user:

```
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SocketAuthenticationInterceptor implements ChannelInterceptor {
    private final JwtTokenProvider tokenProvider;
    private final UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService;

    @Override
    public Message<?> preSend(Message<?> message, MessageChannel channel) {
                    StompHeaderAccessor accessor =
                            MessageHeaderAccessor.getAccessor(message, StompHeaderAccessor.class);
                    if (StompCommand.CONNECT.equals(accessor.getCommand())) {
                        List<String> authorization = accessor.getNativeHeader("Authorization");
                        String jwt = authorization.get(0);
                        final Integer userId = tokenProvider.getUserIdFromJWT(jwt);

                        final UserDetails userDetails = userDetailsService.loadUserById(userId);
                        final UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication =
                                new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, null, userDetails.getAuthorities());
                        accessor.setUser(authentication);
                    }
                    return message;
    }
}
```

Registering the interceptor:

```
@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE + 99)
public class WebSocketAuthenticationConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    private final SocketAuthenticationInterceptor socketAuthenticationInterceptor;

    @Override
    public void configureClientInboundChannel(final ChannelRegistration registration) {
        registration.interceptors(socketAuthenticationInterceptor);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm having exactly the same issue. Did you ever get to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Authenticating the user for a web request is done using **filters** in Springboot. By default there are a bunch of filters which try to authenticate any request. Note that this authentication is done during the handshake and before sending the initial `CONNECT` message. A `CustomInterceptor` is used for handling the messages we receive **not for AuthN**, since the filter itself is unauthn'ing the request the message is not even being received hence the execution is not reaching the interceptor.
So instead write your own custom filter class like so

```
class JwtRequestFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
...
@Override
protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
String requestTokenHeader = request.getHeader("Authorization");
if (requestTokenHeader != null && requestTokenHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
                jwtToken = requestTokenHeader.substring(7);
 }
final Integer userId = tokenProvider.getUserIdFromJWT(jwtToken);
final UserDetails userDetails = userDetailsService.loadUserById(userId);
final UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication =new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, null, userDetails.getAuthorities());
//If you want to set source details
authentication.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
   }
}
```

And then add this custom filter to the list of filters like so in `WebSecurityConfig.java`

```
 @Override
 protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
  ...
   // Add a filter to validate the tokens with every request
        httpSecurity.addFilterBefore(jwtRequestFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class); // Or any other filter of your choice
 }
```

So with this your authentication context is set. 
Useful Links:

1. [Spring Security Architecture](https://spring.io/guides/topicals/spring-security-architecture)
2. [Adding Custom Filter in SpringBoot](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-custom-filter)
3. [More on Web Security in Spring](https://spring.io/guides/gs/securing-web/)
4. [Bearer schema JWT Token](https://jwt.io/introduction/)